# Syntax error on token "else", delete this

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax

I keep on getting this error and I tried mixing it around. But then when I choose the option, it does the option, but then said "you did not enter 1, 2 or 3".

This is the the [full code](http://pastebin.com/a8ky8DP8). How to fix it?

The error is at

```
} else {
    System.out.println("You did not enter 1, 2 or 3");
} else {
    System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong");
}
```

Comment: Please format your code (to remove all of the blank space) and then post the entire block, not an external link.

Comment: look at my answer, you do not use the option parameter right!

Comment: [The if-then and if-then-else Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the code you provided on your paste bin.

You use two else statements, so Java complains as it doesn't know which to go to after the initial if statement.

You need to enter in another conditional statement using else if, then else. For example:

```
if (option == 1){
    Option_1 Optionone = new Option_1();
    Optionone.Withdraw();
}
etc

}else if (nothing entered) {
    System.out.println("You did not enter 1, 2 or 3");
}else{
    System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong");   
}
```

You also have another major problem with your code. You declare the variable option and set it in an if statement, so it only has scope within that if statement. You then come out of the if statement and declare a brand new option variable before the code I provided above. This will not function, as the option integer has no value.

Instead, you need to declare your initial option int outside of your if statement, like so:

```
int number;
int password = 7123;
int amount = 4000;
int option;

if (number == password) {
    etc...
    option = userInput.nextInt();
}
```

Furthermore, you come out of the if statement checking the entered number against the stored password to take input on withdrawing cash etc. This is no good. It means that after the if statement checking number against password is finished, it will automatically proceed to the next block of code.

As the scanner object hasn't been created, the first three if statements will come back false and your else statement will be printed (regardless of whether the input password was correct).

Therefore, I would advise you to put that check in a separare else statement and use a while loop to confirm a correct selection ahs been entered. For example:

```
System.out.println("Please Enter Your Bank Pin.");
Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);
int number;
int password = 7123;
int amount = 4000;
int option;

number = userInput.nextInt();

if (number == password) {
    System.out.println("Pin Accepted");
    System.out.println("You Have Now Entered Harry's Bank!");
    System.out.println("Press The Number Of The Option You Would Like.");
    System.out.println("1.Withdraw Money.");
    System.out.println("2.Put In Money");
    System.out.println("3.Exit Bank");
    Scanner Options = new Scanner (System.in);
    option = userInput.nextInt();
    while (option != 1 || option != 2 || option != 3) {
        System.out.println("You didn't enter a valid number. Try again");
        option = userInput.nextInt();
    }
    if (option == 1){
        Option_1 Optionone = new Option_1();
        Optionone.Withdraw();
    }
    else if (option == 2){
        Option_2 Optiontwo = new Option_2();
        Optiontwo.Deposit();
    }
    else if (option == 3){
        Option_3 Optionthree = new Option_3();
        Optionthree.Exit();
    }
}
else
    System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an incorrect syntax:

```
 }else{
        System.out.println("You did not enter 1, 2 or 3");
 }else{
        System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong");
```

Just do it this way:

```
else {
    System.out.println("You did not enter 1, 2 or 3");
    System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your second `else` statement does not close no `if` statement.

Also, the `option` variable is not in the right scope:

try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Welcome To Harry's Bank");

                //Pin System

                System.out.println("Please Enter Your Bank Pin.");
                Scanner userInput = new Scanner (System.in);   
                        int number;    
                        int password = 7123;    
                        int amount = 4000;   
                        number = userInput.nextInt();
                        int option;

                        if (number == password) {
                            System.out.println("Pin Accepted");
                            System.out.println("You Have Now Entered Harry's Bank!");
                            System.out.println("Press The Number Of The Option You Would Like.");
                            System.out.println("1.Withdraw Money.");
                            System.out.println("2.Put In Money");
                            System.out.println("3.Exit Bank");
                            Scanner Options = new Scanner (System.in);
                            option = userInput.nextInt();
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong");    
                        }


                        if (option == 1){
                                Option_1 Optionone = new Option_1();
                                Optionone.Withdraw();
                        }

                         if (option == 2){
                                Option_2 Optiontwo = new Option_2();
                                Optiontwo.Deposit();
                         }

                         if (option == 3){
                                Option_3 Optionthree = new Option_3();
                                Optionthree.Exit();
                         }else{
                                System.out.println("You did not enter 1, 2 or 3");
                     }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have **TWO** else in a if-else case.

Your nested If statement is not proper. Use it as below

```
    if (number == password) {
        .....
        .....

        if (option == 1) {
        }
        else if (option == 2) {
        }
        else if (option == 3) {

        } else {
            System.out.println("You did not enter 1, 2 or 3");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you the 'else' statement twice in your if-else construct.

You have:

```
if { }
else { }
else { }
```

But you probably want:

```
if { } 
else if { }
else { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two `else` blocks added to an `if`

```
} else {
    System.out.println("You did not enter 1, 2 or 3");
} else {
    System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong");
}
```

Either drop one or club the two `println()`s into one `else` block

```
} else {
    System.out.println("You did not enter 1, 2 or 3");
    System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong"); 
}
```

Take a look at how to use the **[if-then and if-then-else](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)** statements.

Alternatively, I suggest you to make use of the **[Switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)** statements  for better clarity of code.

```
switch (option) {
    case 1:  Option_1 OptionOne = new Option_1();
             OptionOne.Withdraw();
             break;

    case 2:  Option_2 OptionTwo = new Option_2();
             OptionTwo.Withdraw();
             break;

    case 3:  Option_3 OptionThree = new Option_3();
             OptionThree.Withdraw();
             break;

    default: System.out.println("You did not enter 1, 2 or 3");
             System.out.println("The Pin You Entered Was Wrong");
}
```